# Portable Init Script?

Tags: portability, init, upstart, systemd

How to write a portable init Script which works with

- upstart (Ubuntu)
- systemd
- optional init.d

Other platforms (Windows, Android, OS-X) are not important in my context.

Answer (score 2):

Both [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and `upstart` support `sysinit` style scripts. RHEL 6 uses upstart but most scripts are normal `init.d` bash scripts. RHEL 7 and Fedora 19 (and earlier) use `systemd`, but they happily run old init scripts.

You can use normal old style daemon that forks with init script. If the application does not fork on its own you can use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to do the forking for you and directly integrate with separate systemd script. I do not know details about `upstart` except it uses it's own format, but supporting it (if you do not have to support old/current linux systems) seems reasonable only for non-linux distributions. `systemd` is currently Linux specific, though I've seen work being done to port it to BSD.

You may be interested in how they integrated CUPS. Last time I checked the `systemd` "script" starts the daemon with `-f` option (foreground) - `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cupsd -f`. The `init.d` script does not add that flag.

In short - for now use old style `System V` `init.d` script if you want one solution that works everywhere. Add `systemd` support if you have some spare resources and if you have enough, you can certainly support the three systems separately (greatest benefit for the users, but a lot of work).

I'd personally create `init.d` + systemd scripts and would not care about upstart. Chances are `systemd` [will soon replace upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Adoption) ([also look here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/after-linux-civil-war-ubuntu-to-adopt-systemd/)) and `init.d` scripts will remain usable on the rest of the UNIX-es.

Comment: AFAIK systemd and upstart support dependencies: You can say start this service after service `foo`. AFAIK this is not supported by init.d scripts.

Comment: Yes, `init.d` scripts have to enforce this by their own (one script can check, start and/or stop another at any time).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `systemd` allows to run `init.d` scripts, so you can do a script that is portable with `upstart` and `init.d`.
The other thing is that all of them (`systemd`, `init.d`, `upstart`) uses its own syntax. The only solution I see is to create three different scripts that call some application of the most common service interface - a forking service application. That way all of the managers will know how to handle your service. And provide your application with all three kinds of scripts. Then, installer will have to choose what script is to be installed with your service application.